# Where can I find BLYP pseudopotentials?

Tags: quantum-espresso, pseudopotentials, exchange-correlation

[Quantum ESPRESSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_ESPRESSO) doesn't support pseudopotentials for hybrid functional. Instead they [suggest](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/faq/faq-pseudopotentials/#2.7) using pseudopotentials for the non-hybrid functional that is closer to the hybrid one, i.e., PBE for PBE0 and HSE, BLYP for B3LYP.

I have googled and asked ChatGPT, but it failed to find pseudopotentials with BLYP functional. I found it for [Li](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium), [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon), [N](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen), [O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen), and [Cl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine), but I don't need them. I need BLYP pseudopotentials for transition metals, such as [Cu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper), [Fe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron), [Ni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel), [Co](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobalt), etc., and [Mg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnesium) and [Ge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanium) too.

Just like we have plenty of resources for many type of pseudopotentials, do we have a compilation of pseudopotential with BLYP functionals?

Comment: One can use the input_dft option in the &SYSTEM card. Look in the ~/qe-7.2/Modules/funct.f90 for a list of available hybrid functionals. I typically use standard PBE PPT as a starting point for these types of calculations. You can find worked examples in the ~/qe-7.2/PW/examples/EXX_example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try searching for BLYP pseudopotentials here - http://pseudopotentials.quantum-espresso.org/legacy_tables/hartwigesen-goedecker-hutter-pp
. One can generate BLYP and B3LYP pseudopotentials also.